# Calculate cyclomatic complexity from file in different programming language via script

Tags: python, c#, cyclomatic-complexity

I am working on writing a script that outputs information about my written source code.
So far, I am analysing the code with Python scripts that I have written.
There is a `Test.cs` class which is used for this analysis. 
Now I want to calculate the **cyclomatic complexity** from `Test.cs`.

Currently I am working on *Visual Studio Code*. I am aware that *Visual Studio* offers such a functionality and there are also *packages* that I can use for this.

However, I wanted to find out whether it is possible

- a.) to write a Python script which can analyse my `Test.cs` class or
- b.) to create a C# project to analyse the corresponding `Test.cs` class and if so, how can I pass the value for my script?

Because I would like to output and evaluate this value separately for the user.

---

Also I found this interesting documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/how-to-generate-code-metrics-data?view=vs-2022#metricsexe

But here it is not clear to me how I could build and call up the `Metrics.exe` accordingly.

---

Or are there other approaches I could pursue?

I look forward to your feedback.

Comment: The linked article has a sequence of well defined steps. Where are you facing an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest method is probably to call and parse the output of `Metrics.exe`.

If you don't provide `/out`, it will print to stdout, so you can capture it in Python.

I don't use Windows, so I can't test this, but something along the lines of this should work:

```py
import subprocess
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

o = subprocess.run("Metrics.exe", "/project:ConsoleApp20.csproj", capture_output=True, check=True, text=True)
root = ET.fromstring(o.stdout)
print(root)
```

From there, just select the metrics you're looking for.